# elementRef is null after building angular app

Tags: angular, dom, elementref

In a component template, i'm selecting an svg element with ElementRef. It works fine but when i build the app and open it elementRef is null.

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-svg',
      template: `<div id="root">
        <object [data]='trustedUrl' type="image/svg+xml" height="450" width="650" #dataSvg></object>
      </div>`,
      styleUrls: ['./svg.component.css'] 

    })
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private elRef: ElementRef) {    
 }
```

elementRef targeted

```
@ViewChild('dataSvg') dataSvg: ElementRef;
```

pass it to elementRef variable

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.elementRef = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#dataSvg');  
     }
```

after content is loaded, i'm selecting the svg :

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    const elementRef = this.elementRef;

    // when content is loaded...
    elementRef.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
      // ...retrieve svg element
```

> **elementRef.querySelector('svg')** is null

when i run '**npm run build**' and go to dist/index.html, the **contentDocument >  is null** :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to the **[official Doc](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)**, you cannot access to the `@ViewChild` element unless you do it in the **[AfterView](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview)** hook (`AfterViewInit` or `AfterViewChecked` ) instead of the `OnInit` one.

---

- *[You can find here](https://medium.com/@tkssharma/understanding-viewchildren-viewchild-contentchildren-and-contentchild-b16c9e0358e)* a good article about differences between `@ViewChild`, `@ViewChildren`, `@ContentChild` and `@ContentChildren`.

Answer (score 3):

You use `@ViewChild('dataSvg') dataSvg: ElementRef;` but in your template you haven't provided any anchor for `dataSvg`.

There are 2 ways to do this:
1) using @Directive as explained  on [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)
2) Using a template reference `#` :in your case:
`<object ... #dataSvg></object>`

Not mentioned if you already use Directive, but in your template code, you only have an `id=dataSvg`

Comment: uh, but now you have removed the ID part, hence: `this.elementRef = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#dataSvg');` won't work anymore. 
I'm not really sure, why you do this considering you already have the `@viewchild` reference

Comment: No, it' s fixed i use the elementRef this.dataSvg. the problem is in foreground.. i lose the dynamic comportment when it's not running in node. Svg is not loaded with a dynamic component factory

Answer (score 2):

DOM is not completely built yet in `ngOnInit`. You need to wait for children (template here) to be created.

Instead of `ngOnInit`, put your code into `ngAfterViewInit`.

More info on hooks in component lifecycle can be found [in the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Comment: thanks, i did the change on AfterViewInit, but when i'm compiling the app (npm run build) and open index.html into /dist elementRef is null. I want to select the svg child of object element (elementRef.nativeElement.contentDocument)

Answer (score 1):

In the below place, explicitly give read: ElementRef,

@ViewChild('dataSvg') dataSvg: ElementRef;

It should be

@ViewChild('dataSvg', { read: ElementRef }) dataSvg: ElementRef;

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution of compatibility for append SVG element :

in my svg component i set the source of svg with binding innerHTML, when my input changes i'm loading the svg with a service which returns the svg data in a safe way:

binding the data source of SVG in the component :

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-svg',
  template: `<div id="root">
    <div [innerHTML]="svgSafe" type="image/svg+xml" height="450" width="650" #dataSvg></div>
  </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./svg.component.css'] ,
  animations: [

  ]
})
```

load the source of svg with input :

```
 ngOninit() {

    var url = this.data.url;


    var id = 1; 

    if(url === 'assets/object_move.svg') {
       id = 1;
    }

    if(url === 'assets/object_wait.svg') {
      id = 2;
    }


    ..
    var dataSVG;
            this
              .loaderService
              .getSVGData(id)
              .subscribe((dataSvg) => {

      this.svgSafe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(dataSvg.data);

            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a security risk associated with ElementRef:

Permitting direct access to the DOM can make your application more vulnerable to XSS attacks.

https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#description

Consider using Renderer2:

https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2